# Render collection in 2 columns

Tags: knockout.js

Currently I have:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: list">
</div>
```

And need:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: /* 1st half of the list */">
</div>
<div data-bind="foreach: /* 2nd half of the list */">
</div>
```

It would be great to avoid using 2 separate observables or computed.

Comment: *"It would be great to avoid using 2 separate observables or computed."* - Why disregard the one thing specifically designed to do stuff like that?

Comment: I thought it is not the ViewModel's responsibility to reflect UI layout. Am not I right?

Comment: Well, theoretically yes, but HTML is notoriously bad at dynamic vertical columns (i.e. layouts without a predefined item count). You could use CCS `float: left;` and a single `<div>`, but layout would be left-to-right. You could try with CSS `column-count` but that's not supported consistently. Or you could be pragmatic. Pick your poison.

Comment: Thank you @Tomalak I'll keep it in mind. But The question is how to split the list in KO.

Comment: You can use if condition like $index < collection().length/2

Comment: Why don't you let the UI take care of that?
[HTML+CSS](http://csswizardry.com/2010/02/mutiple-column-lists-using-one-ul/)

Comment: @AndrasToth Interesting tip, but as they say themselves, it's useless. Quote: *"Use this wisely... It displays content in an ambiguous manner and should not be used where order of reading is imperative."*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the array `slice` method to create the two collections:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: list.slice(0, list.length / 2) ">
    <span data-bind="text: $data" />
</div>
<div data-bind="foreach: list.slice(list.length / 2)">
    <span data-bind="text: $data" />
</div>
```

If you have an observable array you need to slightly modify your bindings:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: list.slice(0,list().length / 2) ">
    <span data-bind="text: $data"/>
</div>
<div data-bind="foreach: list.slice(list().length / 2)">
    <span data-bind="text: $data"/>
</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/794FT/3/).

Comment: @Tomalak. Its a mistake by me.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use mod 2, like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: list">
    <!--ko if: $index() % 2 == 0 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="with: $parent.list()[$index()+1]" class="col-md-6">
            <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/ko-->
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robgallen/1728389j/

Comment: @Space Monkey You're a genius! I've tried to solve this every which way and was completely stumped. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### A safe and clean example of using an observable array

```
<!-- ko with: myObservableArray -->
    <div data-bind="foreach: $data.slice(0, $data.length / 2)">
        <span data-bind="text: $data"/>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="foreach: $data.slice($data.length / 2)">
        <span data-bind="text: $data"/>
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make an outer table with one row and two cells Inside the first cell put another table with only the even indexes. In the second cell bind to the odd indexes.

```
        <table style="table-layout:fixed;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table style="table-layout:fixed;">
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: someObservableArray">
                            <!--ko if: $index() % 2 == 0 -->
                            <tr>
                                <td data-bind="text: somePropertyInArrayObject"></td>                                 
                            </tr>
                            <!--/ko-->
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table style="table-layout:fixed;">
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: someObservableArray">
                            <!--ko ifnot: $index() % 2 == 0 -->
                            <tr>
                                <td data-bind="text: somePropertyInArrayObject"></td>                                    
                            </tr>
                            <!--/ko-->
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: dd valign="top" to the second td so rows align when there are an odd number of items.